# TileMap Tileset Opacity Messing up

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a tilemap with some layers where the opacity of the images used as the tileset are not 100%. I am running the game in cocos2d-iphone. The problem is that after I play a few levels the opacity of the tilesets get set to 100%. Basically after a few levels have been played, the transparency in the image changes so that everything is opaque. Any ideas as to how may this be caused? I know this is a vague question but I am also quite clueless as to what may be happening.

Comment: how do ypu set opacity initially? May be related to cocos2d's tiles not being sprites unless used as such.

Comment: For some of the PNGs the PNG itself is transparent and for some of the PNGs I set the opacity in the tilemap.

Comment: transparent PNG issue may be fixable by setting the correct blend mode, and forcibly setting it every time you loaded the TMX file

Comment: I have checked that the GL_BLEND is always enabled and that the blend function is always "GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA". So no change is happening there still the weird output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The weird behavior was due to a call to [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB5A1]; for one of my sprite. This was messing up the texture format for all the remaining sprite as the set values is saved in a static variable which does not seem to clear out even when u do a [CCDirector end] and any call to load the texture after this made the texture transparencies to get messed up.